# Functional Coverage - bin that collects all values that are not collected in other bins

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, uvm

```
ipv6_hdr__f_next_header_cp: coverpoint  this.ipv6_hdr.ipv6_f_next_header iff (this.has_ipv6_header){
    bins ipsec_33 = {'h33};
    bins tcp_06 = {'h06};
    bins udp_11 = {'h11};
    bins done_3b = {'h3b};
    bins ipv6_ext_any_other [3] = {[0:'h5], ['h7:'h10], ['h12:'h3a], ['h3c:$]};
}
```

`ipv6_ext_any_other` bin should collect all vals that are not collected by other bins.

`default` might be used, but the problem is that `default` is not an `active` bin, I mean, it is not a part of the func cov metrics.

Is there any other way of defining the `ipv6_ext_any_other` bin?
Alternatively, is there a way of making the `default` an active bin?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
bins ipv6_ext_any_other [3] = {[0:$]} with (!(item inside {'h33,'h06,'h11,'h3b}));
```

Also see https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=4698

Comment: I know that `bins ipv6_ext_any_other [3] = default;` is not the answer, because it will automatically be an `ignore_bins`. Do you know why? It seems crazy.

Comment: Much of the covergroup functionality came from *Vera*, and some conceptual ideas were lost in the syntax transition to SystemVerilog. `ignore_bins` is for pulling out overlapping `bins` from coverage collection. `default` is a debugging aid to capture how many times a sample value did not fall into any prescribed bin. There is no way to capture how those values are distributed.

Comment: many thanks for this answer!

I have also checked out the link, I didn't really understand, is the following syntax:
bins ipv6_ext_any_other [3] = {default}

equivalent to:
bins ipv6_ext_any_other [3] = {[0:$]} with (!(item inside {'h33,'h06,'h11,'h3b}));

cuz, actually I thought {default} should work...

Comment: Yes, they would be the same with my proposed syntax. The difference is whether there are `{}`'s around the `default` keyword.